# Converter string "11092018" em formato data "11-09-2018"?

Tags: php

Como faço para transformar, por exemplo, uma string `"11092018"` em `"11-09-2018"`?

Há alguma função que posso utilizar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Usando a função `date_parse_from_format`

```
$data = date_parse_from_format('dmY', '11092018');

$data['month'] = str_pad($data['month'], 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$data['day'] = str_pad($data['day'], 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

$formatada = "{$data['day']}-{$data['month']}-{$data['year']}";
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/44b6zh)**.

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-parse-from-format.php

### Usando a classe `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', '11092018');

$formatada = $data->format('d-m-Y');
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/QhWnIa)**.

Manual:

> http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php

### Usando a função `preg_match`

```
if (preg_match('/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/', '11092018', $matches)) {
    echo "{$matches[1]}-{$matches[2]}-{$matches[3]}";
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/96FRHI)**.

Manual:

> http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 4):

Tem muitas maneiras.

### Usando a função `substr`

```
$formatada = substr($string,0,2).'-'.substr($string,2,2).'-'.substr($string,4,4);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/8CQ1b0)**.

Manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

### Usando a função `substr_replace`

```
$formatada = substr_replace(substr_replace($string,'-',4,0),'-',2,0);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/1KyIF9)**.

Manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-replace.php

Comment: Não creio que se aplica ao que eu disse, mas de qq forma eu já havia deletado. Se eu tivesse postado direcionado pra alguém, ainda vai. Pena que eu não posso restaurar o comment, senão até poria de volta pra comunidade avaliar, pois no meu entendimento, não houve sarcasmo nenhum. São 2 votos negativos que podem ter sido birra de usuário ou desconhecimento de PHP (o que é muito comum por aqui). E ainda convidei pra sugestão de melhorias. Mas o voto é livre e eu sou o primeiro a defender isso. Note que eu nunca disse que a pessoa deveria revisar o voto, como muitos usuários fazem.

Comment: É o mínimo que eu espero de quem vá votar, afinal, a pergunta é de PHP né? Pq se for votar pq é amigo desse ou daquele usuário, aí não é um critério válido (apesar de ter muita coisa que aparenta ser de clube, cabe à moderação verificar). Notando que meus comentários foram feitos considerando que são 5 negativos em 3 respostas, não foi o fato de darem um -1 na minha resposta. Pode ter uma razão real, mas foge um pouco da normalidade.